# Calcular tiempo transcurrido de una fecha y hora actual a una fecha y hora futura (2022-2023) c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, datetimepicker

buen día he tenido un problema desde hace tiempo, intento calcular la diferencia de años, meses, días, hora y minutos, entre una fecha actual y una fecha futura utilizando DateTimePicker, siempre me da como resultado un día menos, ya que el ultimo día es como sino completara las 24 horas como por un segundo para completar la cantidad de días exactos entre las dos fecha. nota: esto siempre pasa al querer calcular la diferencia de tiempo con una fecha futura, porque si es con una fecha pasada en comparación con la actual si salen los cálculos bien.

supongamos que estos son los datos ingresados por DateTimePicker:

"12/31/2022 06:40:00" DateTimePicker1
"01/08/2023 06:40:00" DateTimePicker2

Resultado erróneo aproximado: 0 años, 0 meses,  7 días, horas 23:59:59

como vemos esta mal ya que debería indicar que tiene 8 días exactos y ninguna diferencia en el tiempo, la cual debería ser cero.

podrían recomendarme una manera de hacer estos cálculos de diferencia con una fecha futura, o referirme algún paquete Nuget y dame ejemplos, les agradezco

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el código que tienes

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Recomendar un paquete, es cierre de pregunta.. lo otro, es interesante.. y que pasa si siempre sumas un segundo, el resultado es correcto???

Comment: Parece un error de Capa 8. Y el código, dónde está?

Answer (score 1):

Primero debes parsear tus fechas, para después hacer la resta y obtener los días, igual podrías compartir tu código para ver como estas haciendo los cálculos

```
var date1 = DateTime.Parse("12/31/2021 06:40:00"); //DateTimePicker1 
var date2 = DateTime.Parse("01/08/2022 06:40:00"); //DateTimePicker2

var days= (date1-date2).TotalDays;
Console.WriteLine(days);
obteniendo como resultado -8, que son los días

var days2= (date1 - date2).ToString(@"dd\d\ hh\h\ mm\m\ ");
Console.WriteLine(days2);
en este formato, obtienes los días, horas, y minutos
08d 00h 00m
```

puedes ver el ejemplo aqui [en este sitio](https://dotnetfiddle.net/28OQom)

Answer (score 0):

Para el cálculo correcto de la diferencia de Años/Meses/Semanas, el Calendario del CultureInfo debe ser considerada:

- años bisiestos versus años no bisiestos
- meses con diferente recuento de días
- años con un recuento de semanas diferente (que varía según el primer día de la semana y la regla de la semana calendario)

La clase **DateDiff** de la Biblioteca de períodos de tiempo para .NET respeta todos estos factores.

Para tu caso yo utilice variables DateTime, pero bien puedes utilizar los controles DateTimePicker :

```
public void DateDiffSample()
{
  DateTime date1 = new DateTime( 2019, 11, 8, 7, 13, 59 );
  Console.WriteLine( "Date1: {0}", date1 );
  
  DateTime date2 = new DateTime( 2022, 3, 20, 19, 55, 28 );
  Console.WriteLine( "Date2: {0}", date2 );
 

  DateDiff dateDiff = new DateDiff( date1, date2 );

  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.GetDescription(6): {0}", dateDiff.GetDescription( 6 ) ); 
}
```

Comment: Estoy iniciando en la programación, me parece interesante lo indicado sobre cultureinfo, podrías dejar un ejemplo de como podría aplicarlo en el cálculo de las dos fechas para que arroje  un buen resultado.